# R and long data type(numeric). Can I avoid precision loss?

Tags: r, long-integer

I have 3 rows of data like this:

```
  1010095104702929164
  1014576908756930874
  103493462503798643
```

And I read them in with :

```
read.csv(file)
```

And I get in R:

```
1 1.010095e+18
2 1.014577e+18
3 1.034935e+17
```

Now when I write them back to file I get this:

```
"1",1010095104702929152
"2",1014576908756930816
"3",103493462503798640
```

These are not the same values. Any way to avoid this?
   I have tried with:

```
read.csv(file, colclasses=c('character'))
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Please expand on what "doesn't work" when you read them as character, because that "works" fine for me. Note that the argument is `colClasses` not `colclasses`.

Comment: It works now. I am not sure what caused it not to work before. I have a lot more columns in original data. I work in R-Studio so not spelling error.

Comment: You mean it works when you spell the argument correctly? What fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

It does work with:

```
read.csv(file, colClasses=c('character'))
```

as Joran pointed out.